Azure Service Bus: Implementing Priority Queues in Node.js (Similar to RabbitMQ)
I'm trying to implement a priority queue in Azure Service Bus using Node.js, similar to what I've achieved with RabbitMQ. In RabbitMQ, I can assign priorities to messages, ensuring high-priority messages are processed first. However, I haven't found a way to achieve the same functionality in Azure Service Bus with Node.js.
I have tried with RabbitMQ and my requirement was satisfied. Attaching code snippets of RabbiMQ
sender.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

function bail(err, conn) {
  console.error(err);
  if (conn) conn.close(function() { process.exit(1); });
}

function on_connect(err, conn) {
  if (err !== null) return bail(err);
 
  // name of queue
  var q = 'hello';
  var msg = 'Hello World!';
  var priorityValue = 0;

  function on_channel_open(err, ch) {
    if (err !== null) return bail(err, conn);
    // maxPriority : max priority value supported by queue
    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false, maxPriority: 10}, function(err, ok) {
      if (err !== null) return bail(err, conn);

      for(var index=1; index<=100; index++) {
             priorityValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
             msg = 'Hello World!' + ' ' + index + ' ' + priorityValue;
             ch.publish('', q, new Buffer(msg), {priority: priorityValue});
             console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
      }

      ch.close(function() { conn.close(); });
    });
  }

  conn.createChannel(on_channel_open);
}

amqp.connect(on_connect);

reciever.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

function bail(err, conn) {
  console.error(err);
  if (conn) conn.close(function() { process.exit(1); });
}

function on_connect(err, conn) {
  if (err !== null) return bail(err);
  process.once('SIGINTunction() { conn.close(); });
  
  var q = 'hello';

  function on_channel_open(err, ch) {
    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false, maxPriority: 10}, function(err, ok) {
      if (err !== null) return bail(err, conn);
      ch.consume(q, function(msg) { // message callback
        console.log(" [x] Received '%s'", msg.content.toString());
      }, {noAck: true}, function(_consumeOk) { // consume callback
        console.log(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C');
      });
    });
  }

  conn.createChannel(on_channel_open);
}

amqp.connect(on_connect);

Expectation:
Is there a way to implement message priorities within a single queue in Azure Service Bus using Node.js?
If not, what alternative approaches can I use to achieve a similar effect (e.g., multiple queues with dedicated consumers)?
Any relevant code snippets would be helpful.
I understand that Azure Service Bus might not natively support priority queues, but any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
Additional details:
Node.js version: v20.13.1
